# Best rest length for "getting your seat"

Tags: road-bike, training, saddle

I am just getting back on my bike after a couple years and have quickly been made to remember that it takes time to get your butt used to the saddle.  I've read articles about "getting your seat" and all pretty much agree that more short rides will help you "get your seat" faster than few long rides.  They also seem to agree that a "short ride" in this case is about an hour (my typical training loop of about 15 miles takes almost exactly an hour right now).

None of the articles that I have read say how often you should ride during this "my butt is bruised" period.  I'm thinking every other day is about right for me, but I'm wondering anyone has more information on this?  Maybe I should be out every day?  Maybe every third day? 4th day? 117th?  I really have no idea.

I'm on a men's Trek 1.1 with a stock saddle... and a sore (not too sore, just normal beginner's sore) butt.

Comment: Surely this will change based on the saddle, whether you're wearing padded shorts, how well the bike fits, and (small consideration) your butt.

Comment: You'll get over the worst of it in a few days.  Don't over-think it.

Comment: Hint:  Some of the pain you may experience on longer rides can be due to the hairs on your butt getting tangled and pulling each other out.  Shaving your butt (especially in the immediate vicinity of the crack) can greatly alleviate this.

Comment: Or using Chamois Creme, which acts as a lubricant on your skin and mostly prevents this issue.

Comment: The only issue I have is soreness, like the feeling of a bruise.  No skin irritation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one good answer to this question, because there are many personal factors which play in.

Your weight, your physical fitness, the quality of the saddle, and whether it fits *your* body well will all be a factor here.

In general, a short (sub 1 hour) ride every 3 days works well for most people.

Consider getting rid of your stock seat, and getting something more fitted and more stable for your body to adapt to it.

I hope that helps.